# Why is the function $\sin(10π t) + \sin (31 t)$ not periodic while its graph looks periodic?

Tags: waves, mathematics

[image]I was going through the book "**Signals-and-Systems-Continuous-and-Discrete**" (4th edition). The question was to check if **Sin(10πt)+Sin(31t)** is periodic or not. The answer present was short and simple "*THE SUM OF TWO SINUSOIDS IS PERIODIC IF THE RATIO OF THEIR RESPECTIVE PERIODS IS RATIONAL*". However the same when tried in DESMOS GRAPH doesn't correspond.

[image]

Comment: But the text clearly says that it is "not" periodic!

Comment: Sorry I had missed the $\pi$ in one factor and not the other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The graph aught to look periodic. Afterall it should be very hard to see that the fraction of the two periods is irrational (which it is, contrary to "ZerotheHeros" comment to your question) since there are always rational numbers arbitrarily close to each irrational.

One could argue that it should even conceptually be impossible to see the effect by simply plotting something on the computer, as in numerics you typically only uses rational numbers internally.

Conclusion: You will have a hard time observing aperiodicity like this by plotting something on the computer. But this doesn't mean the function that you encounter is periodic.

Comment: yeah I had missed the $\pi$ in one argument but not in the other.

Answer (score 2):

This signal is not periodic.  The difficulty is that the period of one is very close to the period of the other.  As a result, it will appear “almost” periodic when plotted over a restricted range of times.

As an extreme example, consider
$$
cos(\omega t)+\cos(\omega’ t)
$$
where $\omega’=\omega+\epsilon$ with $\epsilon$ a very small irrational number.  This would look almost periodic.

Periodic implies there is a time $T$ such that the signal at $t$ is the same as the signal at $t+T$, $t+2T$, $t+3T$, and this of course can only happen when $\omega/\omega’=a/b$ is rational.

Answer (score 2):

The function

$$ x(t) = \sin\left( 10 \pi t \right) + \sin \left( 31 t \right) $$

*is not* periodic, but it is *near* periodic, meaning that $x(t_k)=0$ for every $$t_k = \frac{\pi + 2\pi k }{10\pi-31}$$

You can prove this by manipulating the above into

$$ x(t) = 2 \sin \left( \tfrac{10\pi+31}{2} t \right) \cos \left( \tfrac{10 \pi-31}{2} t \right) $$

and finding the $t$ where the $\cos()$ term is zero.

**But just because a function has zeros at regular intervals does not make it periodic.** This is why visual inspection fails here.

You can prove this because if the function was periodic then $\tfrac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t} x(t)$ would be that same at each $t_k$. But in this case

$$\tfrac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t} x(t) |_{x=x_k} = -(10\pi-31) (-1)^k \cos \left( \frac{\pi (10\pi+31)}{10\pi-31}k + \frac{\pi 31}{10\pi-31} \right)$$

Some of the near roots of $x'$ are

- $k=15$, $t_k=234.15041805$, $x' = 0.00546...$
- $k=478$, $t_k=7228.4500025$, $x' = -0.00003374...$

---

### Appendix

I use the following trig formula

$$ x(t) = \sin(\omega_1 t) + \sin(\omega_2 t) = 2 \sin \left( \tfrac{\omega_1+\omega_2}{2} t \right) \cos \left( \tfrac{\omega_1-\omega_2}{2} t \right) $$

Answer (score 2):

**Because it isn't.** You just aren't eagle-eyed enough.

$10\pi \approx 31.4$. 31 is 31. The difference is about 1.3%. So you'll need to look real close at each apparent "period" to see what's up or, to put it another way, it is small enough to fool you into thinking it is periodic even though it's actually not periodic.

Let's consider that nip between two "periods". Like here.

[image]

Using a computer graphics program, we zoom in, take a small region around each, re-color one blue and overlay.

[image]

You can see they don't match. Otherwise we'd have a nice single up/down wave line that was bluish in one part but not the other. You can see clearly though some of each or the other overlap the white areas.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution stated that function : $\displaystyle \sin (10 \pi t) + \sin (31t)$ is not periodic because it does not have a fundamental time period. But It seems periodic.

This may be due to the fact that when $t's$ are random i.e not anyway near to the fundamental time period, both the functions being periodic and continuous would generate similar output. But when we look in the neighbourhood of the fundamental time period, we would only get to know where the function 'approaches' i.e cannot tell the exact value. Hence it is not periodic in reality when we talk of neighbourhood of fundamental time period.

Thus we can conclude that function is not periodic.